# Why does pressing F3 open Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Whenever I press <kbd>F3</kbd>, my computer opens Chrome. I need <kbd>F3</kbd> for some shortcuts. Why does <kbd>F3</kbd> launch Chrome?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have one of those annoying keyboards that combines the F-keys and the media keys together into one set of physical buttons?  If so you switch between F-functions and Media functions by pressing the <kbd>Fn</kbd> button.  I have known these keyboards to default to using the media keys setting and not the F-key setting at bootup.

Comment: I think I've even seen the Microsoft ones use the media keys per default.

Comment: My laptop has the default set in the BIOS, so you might need to look there to change the behaviour.

Comment: But fn changes f3 to euro sign.

Comment: You can disable it in bios. Basically look for something that reverts the F-Keys and Function keys.